# What's meaning and usage of the colon ":" in this chunk of code?

Tags: c++, class

Sorry for the vague title. I'm woking on a project that need some knowledge of C++. I don't learn C++, and don't have to time to read through a book. So I hope someone is nice enough to give me a start point to look it up.

Here is the code:

```
TurtlebotTeleop::TurtlebotTeleop(): ph_("~"), linear_(1),angular_(0){
   ph_.param("axis_linear", linear_, linear_);
   ph_.param("axis_angular", angular_, angular_);
   ph_.param("axis_deadman", deadman_axis_, deadman_axis_);
   ph_.param("scale_angular", a_scale_, a_scale_);
   ph_.param("scale_linear", l_scale_, l_scale_);
}
```

I know that this chunk of code is defining a method "TurtlebotTeleop". But What's those thing after the colon ":"?

Thank you very much for any input.

Comment: See [this](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/101-constructor-initialization-lists/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a constructor initialization list. It is syntax for initializing the data members of a class.

The "chunk of code" is the definition of the default constructor of `TurtlebotTeleop`. What follows between the `:` and the `{` are initializations of some of the data members of that class. Once you get into the body of the constructor (between the `{` and `}`) all data members have a value, and whatever you do to them is a change to an existing instance, as opposed to an initialization.

Answer (score 0):

The function is a constructor for your class, and one of the things the constructor must do is initialize every member of the class.

The things after the single colon are a short syntax for initializing members of the class.  So ph_ will be set to "~" when this constructor runs.